# Sporadic UnknownHostException on Samsung Galaxy S II

Tags: android, httpclient

In testing an app, I keep getting errors that occur sporadically on only one device: the GT-I9100 (European) Samsung Galaxy S II. These errors do not occur on any other device, not even the SPH-D710 (Sprint) Samsung Galaxy S II.

The URLs used by the app do not change. They are the same that I can type into a web browser, or that the iOS and desktop versions of the app use. But sometimes they throw an UnknownHostException, and sometimes they don't.

Here is a heavily sanitized version of the code I am using:

```
AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance(activity.getString(R.string.user_agent));
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://" + subdomainId + ".website.com/doSomething.aspx");

  try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("parameter1", value1));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("parameter2", value2));
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost, httpContext);

  ... ...
```

Is there any quirk of the Samsung Galaxy S II that could be causing this? It's running Android 2.3.6.

Comment: I saw another example of this in an ACRA crash report for a different app running on a Droid Razr. That code used androidHttpClient.execute(httpPost). The hardcoded URL is perfectly valid, but threw UnknownHostException

Comment: Doesn't an UnknownHostException occur when the device doesn't have an internet connection?

Comment: An unstable (or even inexistent) internet connection can cause an UnknownHostException.

Comment: Problem may well be a flaky dns server rather than the connection itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others said it could be caused by a non-existent internet connection.

Maybe try adding a request retry handler like so..

```
    HttpRequestRetryHandler retryhandler = new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(6, true);

    httpClient.setHttpRequestRetryHandler(retryhandler);
```

That way if the internet goes off for a split second you the httpclient can handle it. [Here](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/exception-handling.html) apache also suggest retrying if you have any transport errors

> Generally transport exceptions are non-fatal and may be recovered from
>   by retrying the failed method.

So I would suggest it is good practice to use the retry handler anyway

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test this and determine if, across devices, this is a reliable solution for this sporadic error... but retrying the Internet connection seems to be the consensus and the best option anyone has put forward.

Answer (score 0):

An UnknownHostException can result from a unreliable or nonexistent internet connection. You should just have a try/catch block to catch these and do whatever steps are necessary to resolve the issue (maybe ask the user to check their internet connection).

I'm guessing that the reason the European version has more issues is because it doesn't have service here (assuming you are working in the U.S.)?